# Como soluciono el error en windows: "No reconoce el comando 'pipenv' "

Tags: python, django, windows

Llevo tiempo intentando solucionar esto y no lo logro, al parecer pip se instala correctamente, porque me aparece la version al poner pip --version, es la pip 23.2.1, pero al intentar instalar django en un entorno virtual con el siguiente comando: pipenv install django==2.1, no reconoce el comando pipenv, que pueda hacer

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Necesito instalar django en un entorno virtual, pero no me reconoce el comando pipenv, entonces no he logrado continuar

Answer (score 0):

Python no trae el módulo [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) integrado, ya que nativamente usa [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Para resolverlo, desde la terminal:

```
python -m pip install pipenv
python -m pipenv install django==2.1
```

Comment: Hola!! muchas gracias, si me funcionó :D